# vignette build fail: knitr unable to interprete Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, cran

I have been building vignettes with `knitr` for several months but about 10 days ago, this message appeared after using `R CMD build` or `devtools::build()`:

> It seems you should call rmarkdown::render() instead of knitr::knit2html() because Release.Rmd appears to be an R Markdown v2 document.

I thought it would be linked to text inside the vignette so I reduced it to a minimal reproducible example:

```
title: "Release"
output:
  html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Release}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

Release
```

### Force evaluation

I tried to force the evaluation of the Rmarkdown adding:

```
params:
  force_v1: TRUE
```

### Change vignette builder

I also tried to replace the `VignetteEngine` by `rmarkdown::render` and editing the `VignetteBuilder` in the Description file. This skips the vignette building as `rmarkdown`does not seem to be a known vignette builder.

### Question:

Is there a way to solve this using `knitr` or alternatively by building vignettes with `rmarkdown`?

### Additional information

I tried to build the package both on Windows and Centos, with different versions. Failing build information can also be found [here](https://travis-ci.org/DeveauP/QuantumClone/builds/153009785)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these settings, and they work:

```
output:  rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{the title}
```

Comment: It worked on Windows R 3.2.2 but fails on CentOs with R 3.2.0, with the same warning message as previously. Any idea why?

Comment: It could be that you are using different versions of `knitr` and/or `rmarkdown` on the CentOS system.  Or it could be a bug in R 3.2.0; generally it's best to use the highest value of z that's available for R x.y.z .

Answer (score 0):

You should use instead

```
%\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}
```

with all the packages up to date.